# Verify image height, width and filetype before uploading with ImageField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I will soon enable a friend to upload images through the admin interface of my little Django project. I would like him to follow two rules :

- Images must be 2000 x 1200 pixels
- Images must be PNG files

My current model looks like this :

```
class MapLayout(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)

    def upload_details(instance, filename):
        path = "maps/" # Upload location
        format = instance.slug + '.png' # Filename
        return os.path.join(path, format)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_details)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

For reference, I am running Django 1.6 with Python 3.4

How can I verify image height, width and filetype before upload ?

Comment: _"Verify image height, width and filetype **before** uploading"_ If you really want to do that _before_ downloading, you have to look for a client-side technology. That would not dispense you to check server-side though, as you cannot trust clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like Pillow to do so:

```
from PIL import Image

image=Image.open(filepath)
image.size # (width,height) tuple
image.format # (keeps the image format)
```

You can find more information at the official documentation:

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/